# MySQL configuration adjustment for 1G DB, 8GB Ram

Tags: mysql, database-performance, my.cnf

I have a MySQL DB size of 1GB, running on dedicated server with 4C/4T, 8GB of Ram and an SSD drive.

My website is having over 200.000 articles and when using search functions (SELECT queries), it gets slow or unresponsive to the point I need to kill the processes from my WHM panel.

I asked for support today to show me my.conf file and as I can see, It's running on defaults. Here is the data:

```
max_connections = 150
max_user_connections = 100
query_cache_size = 64M
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 64M
max_allowed_packet=268435456
table_open_cache = 256
sort_buffer_size = 1M
net_buffer_length = 16K
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 32M
innodb_file_per_table
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_type = on

# This setting allows the use of asynchronous I/O in InnoDB.
# The following files track usage of this resource:
# - /proc/sys/fs/aio-max-nr
# - /proc/sys/fs/aio-nr
# Default limit is 65536, of which a single instance of mysql uses 2661 out   of the box
innodb_use_native_aio = 1
default_storage_engine = MyISAM
open_files_limit=10000
```

In the given values, I don't see the presence of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and the guy from the support asked would I like to add it to my.conf. I read it's important value, so it probably should be added?

The largest tables in my DB are InnoDB and MyISAM is the default storage engine.

What would be the recommended configuration here and which values would need to be adjusted to gain optimal performance?

Is there anything else needs to be defined in my.cnf like `innodb_buffer_pool_size` or `innodb_log_file_size`?

Comment: Most likely, the problem is not config file-related. I would look at the SQL queries that take too long and run the EXPLAIN command on them. Some indexes may be missing, resulting in full table scans. The second most popular error is reading the whole big SELECT result set into RAM in one go with fetchall() or equivalent.

Comment: @MikeBessonov Queries are pretty much the way they need to be in order for Search function performs an actual search. I could use FULLTEXT instead of LIKE on some queries, but that would cause me to lose wildcarding, which is important part of the search for my site. For that reason, I was thinking that pushing the database configuration to have a better performance would definitely have an impact on the site performance overall.

Comment: Can you identify the SQL query that takes far too long to execute?

Comment: @MikeBessonov Yes, I know exactly which queries are running at which point. And it's usually more than one query (2-4 per search), because of the site features. Each query takes 0.6sec to load. Having MATCH AGAINST instead of LIKE, lowers it to 0.0002sec, but then the search doesn't work as I want it to. So my guess would be to update DB settings so that even LIKE searches would be faster. At least I think, not really an expert on this field.

Comment: MATCH uses a FULLTEXT index, while LIKE can use a "normal", unless the search pattern _starts_ with a wildcard (and it should not). 0.6 secs per query is a lot, and compared to 0.0002 sec it is striking. Probably you need to add an index (indexes) to some columns? EXPLAIN tells you exactly which indexes are used by a specific SELECT query.

Comment: Percona have a wizard for MySQL conf files which might be handy: https://tools.percona.com/wizard

Comment: Thanks guys, but I was initially looking for a recommendation from an expert in this field.

Comment: If `MATCH ... AGAINST` returns too many rows, combine your tactics: use `WHERE MATCH (...) AGAINST (...) AND col1 LIKE expr`.  MySQL is smart enough to execute the fulltext part first, to eliminate non-matching rows quickly, and then test only the remaining rows using `LIKE`, which gives you fulltext's speed + like's precision and avoids full table scans.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "tune your way out of performance problems", but here are settings to change:

```
key_buffer_size = 800M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1500M
```

InnoDB is preferred to MyISAM.  (If you change, then more changes will be needed.)

What version are you using?

Usually performance depends on indexes and query formulation.  Let's see a slow query, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for its table(s).

`0.0002sec` sounds like it was found in the Query cache.  Run timings thus:  `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to avoid unrealistic amounts.

Answer (score 0):

For MYISAM tables:

Key_buffer_size = should be 20%  to 30% of Physically RAM memory. Calculate according to your 8 GB RAM.

I would suggest you to change the engine of MYSQL to INNODB

Third one : Your query slow because of lack of indexes or query optimization. USE EXPLAIN plan for query and optimize according to it by adding index to table.